# Regarding Footnote and Reference

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, xfootnote

I want my

1- a footnote is to be displayed while I show the item where I mentioned it and the rest footnote be displayed in similar manner. (in the given code, on page 1 no footnote should be displaced, and on page 2 only the first footnote should be displayed and on page 3 both footnotes should be displayed)

2- reference displayed having numerical numbers like 1. 2. 3. or [1], [2], [3], etc

The code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
\usebeamerfont{footline}%
\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
\hspace{1em}%
\insertframenumber}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}


\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item This is A.
\pause

\item This is B. \footnote{Reference 1}
\pause

\item This is C. \footnote{Reference 2}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{References}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\tiny % Reduce the font size in this block
%\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em} % Get rid of the default "References" section title
\nocite{*} % Insert publications even if they are not cited in the poster
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bb}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note - bb  file  is stored in the same folder in Notepad as below

```
@book{y,
  title={Basic theory },
  author={Y, Rogg},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

@article{d,
  title={Inequalities},
  author={D, Randall },
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Information Theory},
  volume={53},
  number={6},
  pages={1945--1965},
  year={2007},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{h,
  title={Advance theory},
  author={H, Bagg},
  booktitle={IEEE Workshop on },
  pages={1--5},
  year={2007},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: "Same folder in Notepad"? I'm not sure I understand what that means, but please tell me you're not using Windows Notepad to do LaTeX.

Comment: You can use `\footnote<2->{\cite{h}}` for a footnote that first appears on slide two and later, and  `\footnote<3->{\cite{y}}` for a footnote that only appears on slide three and beyond, etc., But I'm not sure if you just want the numbers `[1]`, `[2]`, etc., to appear there (which is what you'll get with these settings) or the full text of the bibitem/full bibliographical information in the footnote itself?

Comment: @frabjous Sir,  I made a folder and in that folder, I have the TexStudio file and a BibTex file named "bb".

Comment: @frabjous \footnote<2->{}  This worked! Thank you.

Comment: @frabjous Sir, using the BibTex file how I generate a list of references having the S.No. 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: If you mean on the bibliography slide itself, you probably just need to use a different template for the bibliography items. `\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]` would give you something more like the default look, which would be a numbered style in your case. But see the [beamer user's guide](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) page 102.